# How do I iterate through an array in an Angular component HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting error NG0900 (`Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`) when attempting to iterate.

My class:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public share?: share[] = [];

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.post<share[]>('/api/member/shares/get', { "getSharesRequestDto": { "accountNumber": "x123" } }).subscribe(result => {
      this.share = result;
      console.log(this.share);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}

interface share {
  id: string;
  description: string;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="share">
  <div *ngFor="let s of share">
    <span>{{ s.id }}</span>
    <span>{{ s.description }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The object that's logged to the console:

```
{
    "share": [
        {
            "id": "x00",
            "description": "desc 00"
        },
        {
            "id": "x01",
            "description": "desc 01"
        }
    ]
}
```

My API request object according to Swagger:

```
{
  "getSharesRequestDto": {
    "accountNumber": "string"
  }
}
```

My API response:

```
{
  "share": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm new to Angular and don't understand the error message.  It looks like I have an object containing an array, but the `*ngFor` should iterate through the array in the object.

I've tried mapping the object to an anonymous array, I've tried removing the type and changing to any[], but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is the '/api/member/shares/get' perhaps a get request?

Comment: It's a POST, the only reason the name is `/api/member/shares/get` because the body has sensitive data.

Comment: can you share the template, how you are using the ngFor?

Comment: probabily you should change it to `this.share = result.share;`

Comment: When I tried that, I get the following error: `TS2339: (TS) Property 'share' does not exist on type 'share[]'.`

Comment: your API doesn't return array, so you should change it to: http.post<{ share: share[] }>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API doesn't return the array, it return the object with contains a property share which have list. You can update api call like that:

```
constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.post<{ share: share[] }>('/api/member/shares/get', { "getSharesRequestDto": { "accountNumber": "x123" } }).subscribe(result => {
      this.share = result.share;
      console.log(this.share);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

api is returning data in object form and you are iterating over the object that's why you are getting error.

```
this.share = result;
console.log(this.share);
```

Tried to change the above code with this one

```
this.share = result.share;
console.log(this.share);
```

Comment: When I tried that, I get the following error: `TS2339: (TS) Property 'share' does not exist on type 'share[]'.`

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot how you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the actual response from the API, you are just missing accessing the `shared` array as:

```js
this.shared = result.shared;
```

I recommend handling the HTTP logic call to a service, also, you should go with the reactive approach when subscribing to the API result with the `async` pipe so you don't have to handle the subscription, additionally, instead of handling the HTTP call in the constructor, I suggest you do that in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook, it's where you usually handle all the code initialization:

**Service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  getShare(body: yourType): Observable<Share[]> {
    return http.post<Share[]>('/api/member/shares/get', body).pipe(
      map(response => response.share)
    );
  }
}
```

**Component ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  share$!: Observable<Share[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const body = { "getSharesRequestDto": { "accountNumber": "x123" } };
    this.share$ = this.getShare(body);
  }
}
```

**Component template**

```html
<div *ngIf="share$ | async as shares">
  <div *ngFor="let share of shares">
    <span>{{ share.id }}</span>
    <span>{{ share.description }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep the data types in upper case as well, so instead of `share`, it should be `Share`